geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable in pyspark df
I have this code:
def obter_latitude(cep):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="name_of_your_app")
    location = geolocator.geocode(cep)
    try:
        if location:
            return float(location.latitude)
    except GeocoderTimedOut:
        return obter_latitude(cep)

obter_lat_udf = sf.udf(obter_latitude, FloatType())

The 'CEP' is a column in a DataFrame Pyspark with 756 rows, but when I run the code in 'cep' column:
df_out = ceps_mod.select('CEP').withColumn("latitude", obter_lat_udf(sf.col('CEP')))

Return this error :
geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=14010-060&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)"))

How to fix this error for code run in 756 rows of 'CEP' column df pyspark?

Try: geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="name_of_your_app", timeout=30). Means your request is out of the allowed limits, takes time. Or reduce the size of your request.

the code don't run! Keeps trying to run for a long time without any output

I didn't understand what you need, I already sent the error in the question

Ok, I'm waiting for help. Thanks for try. :)
